# How to read table from PDF using itextsharp?

Tags: pdf, itext

I am having an problem with reading a table from pdf file. It's a very simple pdf file with some text and a table. The tool i am using is itextsharp. I know there is no table concept in PDF. After some googling, someone said it might be possible to achieve that using itextsharp + custom ITextExtractionStrategy. But I have no idea how to start it. Can someone please give me some hints? or a small piece of sample code?

Cheers

Comment: As you did not provide a sample PDF, your question can only be answered in general. Thus, if you really only desire to read one specific table (or a specific kind of tables), you might want to provide a sample PDF to get specific answers.

Comment: See this post and the links within it http://stackoverflow.com/a/7515625/231316

Answer (score 3):

This code is for reading a table content. all the values are enclosed by ()Tj, so we look for all the values, you can do anything then with the string resulst.

```
    string _filePath = @"~\MyPDF.pdf";
    public List<String> Read()
    {
        var pdfReader = new PdfReader(_filePath);
        var pages = new List<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < pdfReader.NumberOfPages; i++)
        {
            string textFromPage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, pdfReader.GetPageContent(i + 1)));

            pages.Add(GetDataConvertedData(textFromPage));
        }

        return pages;
    }

    string GetDataConvertedData(string textFromPage)
    {
        var texts = textFromPage.Split(new[] { "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None)
                                .Where(text => text.Contains("Tj")).ToList();

        return texts.Aggregate(string.Empty, (current, t) => current + 
                   t.TrimStart('(')
                    .TrimEnd('j')
                    .TrimEnd('T')
                    .TrimEnd(')'));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This Code is just for read the PDF file you'll need the

```
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser;
```

from the dll itextsharp.dll

```
var pdfReader = new PdfReader(_filePath);

for (int i = 0; i < pdfReader.NumberOfPages; i++)
{
   var locationTextExtractionStrategy = new LocationTextExtractionStrategy();

   string textFromPage = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, i + 1, locationTextExtractionStrategy);

   textFromPage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(textFromPage)));

   //Do Something with the text
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a more manual way, but it can be useful.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Lê uma tabela de um pdf
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pdf">Caminho do PDF</param>
    /// <param name="origemXPag1">Inicio da leitura no eixo X para a primeira página</param>
    /// <param name="origemYPag1">Inicio da leitura no eixo Y para a primeira página</param>
    /// <param name="linhasPag1">Quantidade de linhas da primeira página</param>
    /// <param name="origemXOutrasPag">Inicio da leitura no eixo X para as demais páginas</param>
    /// <param name="origemYOutrasPag">Inicio da leitura no eixo Y para as demais páginas</param>
    /// <param name="linhasOutrasPag">Quantidade de linhas das demais páginas</param>
    /// <param name="alturaLinha">Altrura da linha</param>
    /// <param name="colunas">Nome e largura das colunas</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static List<Dictionary<string, string>> LerTabelaPDF(string pdf, float origemXPag1, float origemYPag1, int linhasPag1, float origemXOutrasPag, float origemYOutrasPag, int linhasOutrasPag, float alturaLinha, Dictionary<string, float> colunas)
    {
        // Primeira página
        float origemX = origemXPag1;
        float origemY = origemYPag1;
        int quantidadeLinhas = linhasPag1;

        var resultado = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
        using (PdfReader leitor = new PdfReader(pdf))
        {
            var texto = string.Empty;
            for (int i = 1; i <= leitor.NumberOfPages; i++)
            {
                if (i > 1)
                {
                    origemX = origemXOutrasPag;
                    origemY = origemYOutrasPag;
                    quantidadeLinhas = linhasOutrasPag;
                }
                for (int l = 0; l < quantidadeLinhas; l++)
                {
                    var dados = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                    int c = 0;
                    float deslocamentoX = 0;
                    foreach (var coluna in colunas)
                    {
                        RectangleJ rect = new RectangleJ(origemX + deslocamentoX, origemY + (l * alturaLinha), coluna.Value, alturaLinha);
                        RenderFilter filter = new RegionTextRenderFilter(rect);
                        ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new FilteredTextRenderListener(new LocationTextExtractionStrategy(), filter);
                        texto = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(leitor, i, strategy);

                        dados.Add(coluna.Key, texto);
                        c++;
                        deslocamentoX += coluna.Value;
                    }
                    if (dados != null)
                        resultado.Add(dados);
                }
            }
        }
        return resultado;
    }
```

using:

```
        var colunas = new Dictionary<string, float>();
        colunas.Add("cod", 20);
        colunas.Add("desc", 300);

        var registros = LerTabelaPDF(pdf, 19, 75, 9, 19, 40, 13, 40, colunas);
        var cod = registros[0]["cod"];
```

Comment: You parse the same page completely many times, each time to extract a different portion of it. This takes much longer than parsing it only once into a regular `LocationTextExtractionStrategy` and then retrieving the contents of those different page regions by calling `LocationTextExtractionStrategy.getResultantText(TextChunkFilter)` with a respectively matching `TextChunkFilter`. In a similar context with iText 7 that switch made the extraction [87.6 times faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48597948?rq=1#comment84346968_48632031)...

Answer (score -1):

So 10 years later I came across the same problem, after fighting with ITextSharp for about 3 days I looked elsewhere and found Spire.office nuget to be really helpful in this task, the PdfTableExtractor there seems to work perfectly for my needs, used tutorial here to guide me https://medium.com/@alexaae9/c-how-to-convert-pdf-to-excel-b32a436294d0

in the link they show how to convert an invoice with a table to an excel sheet.

I adapted this to only extract the table and used it for my needs

the given example:

```
using System;
using Spire.Pdf;
using Spire.Pdf.Utilities;
using Spire.Xls;
namespace ExportPdfTaleToExcel
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Load a sample PDF document
            PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument();pdf.LoadFromFile(@"C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\invoice.pdf");
            //Create a PdfTableExtractor instance
            PdfTableExtractor extractor = new PdfTableExtractor(pdf);
            //Extract tables from the first page
            PdfTable[] pdfTables = extractor.ExtractTable(0);
            //Create a Workbook object,
            Workbook wb = new Workbook();
            //Remove default worksheets
            wb.Worksheets.Clear();
            //If any tables are found
            if (pdfTables != null && pdfTables.Length > 0)
            {
                //Loop through the tables
                for (int tableNum = 0; tableNum < pdfTables.Length; tableNum++)
                {
                    //Add a worksheet to workbook
                    String sheetName = String.Format("Table - {0}", tableNum + 1);
                    Worksheet sheet = wb.Worksheets.Add(sheetName);
                    //Loop through the rows in the current table
                    for (int rowNum = 0; rowNum < pdfTables[tableNum].GetRowCount(); rowNum++)
                    {
                        //Loop through the columns in the current table
                        for (int colNum = 0; colNum < pdfTables[tableNum].GetColumnCount(); colNum++)
                        {
                            //Extract data from the current table cell
                            String text = pdfTables[tableNum].GetText(rowNum, colNum);
                            //Insert data into a specific cell
                            sheet.Range[rowNum + 1, colNum + 1].Text = text;
                        }
                    }
                    //Auto fit column width
                    sheet.AllocatedRange.AutoFitColumns();
                }
            }
            //Save the workbook to an Excel file
            wb.SaveToFile("ExportTableToExcel.xlsx", ExcelVersion.Version2016);
        }
    }
}
```

I used the same logic without saving the sheet

```
using System;
using Spire.Pdf;
using Spire.Pdf.Utilities;
using Spire.Xls;
namespace TableExtracxtor
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Load PDF document
            PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument();
            pdf.LoadFromFile(file);
            //Create a PdfTableExtractor instance
            PdfTableExtractor extractor = new PdfTableExtractor(pdf);
            //Extract tables from the first page
            PdfTable[] pdfTables = extractor.ExtractTable(0);
            if (pdfTables != null && pdfTables.Length > 0)
            {
                //Loop through the tables
                for (int tableNum = 0; tableNum < pdfTables.Length; tableNum++)
                {
                     int rowCount = pdfTables[tableNum].GetRowCount();
                    int colCount = pdfTables[tableNum].GetColumnCount();
                    string[][] text = new string[rowCount][colCount];
                    //Loop through the rows in the current table
                     for (int rowNum = 0; rowNum < rowCount ; rowNum++)
                     {
                         //Loop through the columns in the current table
                         for (int colNum = 0; colNum < colCount ; colNum++)
                         {
                              //Extract data from the current table cell 
                                text[rowNum][colNum] = pdfTables[tableNum].GetText(rowNum, colNum);
                         }
                     }
                 }
             }                 
         }
    }
}
```

and then used the text array as needed

Comment: Ilan, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: thanks mozway, added the main idea for extracting the table