# Is there any way to optimize pdfreader itextsharp?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, pdf, itext

There is a method that many times reads text from different pages of a pdf document using a rectangle. Accordingly, the larger the file, the slower everything is processed, I tried to use Parallel.Foreach, but I didn't get a substantial increase in processing speed, everything seems to be hampered by PdfReader.

The method is something like this:

```
var lst = new ConcurrentBag<Test3>();
using(var reader = new PdfReader(byteArr))
{
    Parallel.Foreach(areas, t => 
    {
        var pageSize = reader.GetPageSize(t.PageNumber);
        var rectangle = GetRectagle(t.AreaData, pageSize);
        var text = GetTextFromRectangle(reader, rectagle, t.PageNumber);
        lst.Add(text);
    }
}

public string GetTextFromRectagle(PdfReader reader, Rectangle rect, int pageNum)
{
    RenderFilter[] filter = {
       new RegionTextRenderText()
    };

    ITextExtractionStrategy strategy =
                new FilteredTextRenderListener(new 
    LocationTextExtractionStrategy(), filter);
    return PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, pageNumber, strategy);
}
```

Comment: Is there really at most one rectangle per page?

Comment: Approximately 900 rectangle areas per page

Comment: Arg. Then it's clear why your code takes some time to execute. You don't show your `GetTextFromRectangle`, I assume it upon each call parses the page with a region filter. Thus, for *900 rectangle areas per page* you parse each page 900 times. Instead you should parse each page only once and restrict the text to extract.

Comment: ItextSharp does all the work, added description of the GetTextFromRectagle method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you mentioned in a comment that there are

> Approximately 900 rectangle areas per page

and added your `GetTextFromRectangle` code, the cause of the problem became clear: *For each* of your pre-defined rectangles you make iText parse the *whole content* of the page the rectangle is on into a filtered text extraction strategy you expect to be focused on the respective rectangle area.

*<sup>By the way, even worse, I don't see you using the `Rectangle rect` parameter in your `GetTextFromRectangle` method, thus after all you actually do not even focus on the respective rectangle!</sup>*

**So you parse each page approximately 900 times, each time throwing away most of the parsed information, instead of only once and retrieving the text from the pre-parsed data from each of those 900 rectangles per page.**

This is waste of resources in its purest form!

What you should do instead, is

- sort and separate your `areas` by their respective page and
- for each of the pages

  - once (**and only once**) parse the content of that page into an unfiltered `LocationTextExtractionStrategy` and
  - for each rectangle on that page use the `GetResultantText(TextChunkFilter)` method of the strategy instance with a `TextChunkFilter` that filters by position (whether the chunk in question is inside the rectangle at hand) to retrieve the area text.

---

As an aside, in case of iText 7 instead of iText 5 (for .Net, formerly called iTextSharp) that `GetResultantText` overload with a `TextChunkFilter` is missing but you can emulate it, cf. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48632031/1729265).

Comment: This helped, the processing is now instant, thank you