# iText7: How to get Text from PDF with Rectangle information

Tags: pdf, itext

I am using iTextSweep to search regex in a PDF file. It give me Rectangle as the result. Then I want to get the text with the result.

Is there any way to get the correct text from `x, y, width, height` with iText?

I am using the function from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48597948/text-extraction-from-a-pdf-using-itext7-how-to-improve-its-performance).

It gives the correct answer for most times, but not always.

> For example, if I search `bbb` in `aaa-bbb-ccc`, it still give me `aaa-bbb-ccc` as extracted Text, even the Rectangle just cover `bbb`.

Answer (score 1):

This is because all text parts that intersect the region will be returned.
If aaa-bbb-ccc is available as one piece of text in the document, it will be returned as a whole.

You can split up the text chunk yourself by calculating the position of each character in the chunk and intersecting them with you area. The location of the text chunk is available via the TextChunk class.